# it is written in my operating system book that signals are synchronous or asynchronous

Tags: unix

it is written in my operating system book that signals are synchronous or asynchronous but I dont get that? I believe that blocked functions are synchronous right? then isnt blocking the current process the only choice after a signal occurs?how can they be asynchronous then?

Comment: yep I also think it's a lie

Comment: blocking: You issue the signal or receive it, something happens, your flow continues. unblocking: You issue the signal, your flow continues, something may happen in another execution flow. There are in fact synchronous & asynchronous signals: For example SIGKILL is asynchronous: you issue the Kill, your program continues and the victim will eventually get the KILL message then die in a time in the future. After sending a KILL, you don't know when the victim will die. However, SIGSEV is synchronous, you get it exactly when there's been the segmentation fault, and in the same execution flow.

Comment: That is a fantastic response.  You should post that as an answer.